# .htaccess url rewriting failed overnight

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

There is something strange going on lately.
The following htaccess redirect / url rewriting code worked perfectly fine for a month. But started giving error code 500 today.
I asked my hosting provider he said that he migrated all the code to a new server. I don't understand why its not working now. The same code worked fine for almost a month.

What i want to achieve :

```
www.example.com/22     ---should go to-->     www.example.com/view.php?iid=22
```

Code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) view.php?iid=$1 [NC, L]
```

PHP version : 7.2

Comment: If "they migrated" then they should be able to tell the differences. So _why_ things broken and how you are supposed to fix them. If they can't or won't then it is time to switch your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ view.php?iid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That is:

Use anchor `$` to match only digits in URI and no spaces in side the flags `[...]`

Comment: Possible that you would have done some investigation on your end but you can see that my answer that solves the problem was posted 13 min before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but the issue got fixed by removing NC from [NC, L]

New code looks like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$   view.php?iid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You didn't only remove `NC` you also added the anchor, as the other answer instructed. The `NC` is for case insensitivity, numbers have no case so that had no affect.

Comment: If you note that my answer has already solved this problem for you by removing `NC` and adding anchor.

Comment: `I don't know how but the issue got fixed by removing NC from [NC, L]`: This **how** has been answered in my answer. You were getting `500` error due to presence of space between `NC,` and `L`.

Comment: but why is this happening on my new server ? on my old server the same code worked